# Binary Safety redis

Tags: file, binary, redis, computer-science

In the Redis Protocol specification, it mentions that:

"Status replies are not binary safe and can't include newlines." What does it mean for a string/file to be binary safe? And why can't status replies in redis be binary safe?

Comment: in redis data of keys and keys names ARE binary safe, here it's the redis commands reply who are not binary safe, just standard ascii strings, much easier for you to deal with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A binary safe string parser accounts for all possible values `0 - 255` in a single character within a string, the string is probably not null terminated (it's length is known otherwise). If a string parser isn't binary safe, it's expecting a null terminated string (a binary `0` at the of the string).

Usually, string parser are not binary safe. Many parses expect normal printable characters and a `0` at the end of a string. If there is not a `0` at the end of this kind of string, there could easily be a segmentation fault.

Binary safe parsers are probably parsing arbitrary data (may be text or something else).

Edit:

"What does it mean for a string/file to be binary safe?"

- It's the text parser that is binary safe, not the string/file itself. However, if a string is called binary safe, I would suspect it means that it is a null-terminated string with standard ascii characters.

"And why can't status replies in redis be binary safe?"

- Because the parser implementation that checks replies *ends* at the first instance of `\r\n`. This is how the parser figures out the length of the string. So if it's finds a `\r\n` before the end of the reply, it stops parsing and disregards everything afterwards.

Unless status replies need to send binary data, there would be no need for them to be binary safe.

Comment: I think you meant to say: "However, if a string is called binary safe, I would suspect it means that it is _not_ a null-terminated string."

Comment: @platypus I meant it the way I said it. but I think since it's not really a term that's associated with a string, there's not really a right answer to that.

Comment: Your very first sentence contradicts your sentence "However, if a string is called binary safe, I would suspect it means that it is a null-terminated string..."

Comment: "the string is probably not null terminated" vs "I would suspect it means that it is a null-terminated string"

Comment: I'm not contradicting myself. Notice the difference between a string *parser* and the string itself. Strings aren't called binary safe. It's the string *parsers* that may or may not be binary safe

Comment: according to http://redis.io/topics/data-types, "binary safety" means the strings can contain any type of data. i guess that means the strings won't be modified by Redis. The replies of Redis aren't binary safe because the receiver of the replies might change them (inadvertently). that's my guess

Comment: While I agree that there is no contradiction (because in the first phrase you talk about a string parser, and later about a string), the phrase "However, if a string is called binary safe, I would suspect it means that it is a null-terminated string with standard ascii characters" doesn't help to clarify things. It actually makes it harder to understand, and causes the confusion brought up by the OP.